# CSS - Padding won't work

Tags: html, css, fullpage.js

I'm having this small problem where my `padding` won't work.

I've tried to have it on the container, the parent element and the paragraphs inside them, 
but none of these works.

Here's my code:

```
    <div class="slide" id="slide_3" data-anchor="slide3">

    <div class="container">

        <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>    

        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>


<p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</p>

<p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</p>

     ...
```

I'm using the fullpage.js plugin, if you're wondering.

```
.container {
color: #C38FCC;
font-family: Nexa, Century Gothic;
font-weight: 300;
font-size: 0.75em;
padding: 25px;
}

#slide_3 {
padding: 25%;
}

p {
padding: 25%;
color: black;
}
```

None of these works, and even the `p` elements `color` won't change.

Comment: Given the limited code provided, looks OK: http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/NghSw/

Comment: your code is working fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the option the plugin provides for it.

`paddingTop` and `paddingBottom` as you can see [in the documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#initialization)

Comment: What about horizontal padding, which is what I'm looking for?

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem. You just have to provide a fiddle showing your problem or otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Comment: Didn't fix the specific problem, but another one. Thanks.